# can Jardiff support Pack200 (.pack.gz)?

Tags: java-web-start

I want to implement Pack200 into our existing JWS application. But recently in my local POC, I am not able to simulate Jardiff with Pack200 file.

Eg,
I have 2 version of jar say

```
1.test__V1.jar 
2.test__V2.jar (additional one jar in lib folder)
```

I am able to get the jar file with the differences(additional one jar in lib folder) between both jar with below URL

```
http://localhost/app/test.jar?version-id=2&current-version-id=1
```

With Pack200 I have prepared 2 gz files based on the above mentioned jar files as following

```
1.test.jar.pack__V1.pack.gz
2.test.jar.pack__V2.pack.gz
```

I will have to always download the full file with below request URL

```
http://localhost/app/test.jar.pack.gz?version-id=2&current-version-id=1
```

Hence then I have a doubt that whether Jardiff is able to support Pack200(.pack.gz) version of file or not. Hope you guys can provide me some guidance here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am having a look at this, because I want to implement jardiff support in [my gradle plugin](http://github.com/tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin). Most probably you are using the JnlpDownloadServlet from Sun. I had a look at it's [sourcecode](https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/webstart/webstart-jnlp-servlet/src/main/java/jnlp/sample/servlet/JnlpDownloadServlet.java). At least the version at the above url does not support pack200 for the jardiff files.

The servlet does the following for every request to a jar file:

```
def (file, mime-type) = find requested file {
    if version-id and current-version-id given and jardiff is smaller than file__V${version-id}.jar.pack.gz
        -> (jardiff.jar, application/x-java-archive-diff)
    else if version-id given
        -> (file__V${version-id}.jar, application/java-archive)
    else 
        -> (file.jar, application/java-archive)
}
if file found {
    if ${file}.pack.gz exists
        return ${file}.pack.gz with $mime-type and content-encoding header pack200-gzip
    else if ${file}.gz exists
        return ${file}.gz with $mime-type content-encoding header gzip
    else 
        return ${file} without $mime-type content-encoding header
}
```

If the returned file is the jardiff or the jar is encoded in the mime-type header.

If pack200 is used is encoded in the content-encoding header. The [JNLP Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jnlp-1.5-mr-spec-oth-JSpec/jnlp-1_5-mr-spec.pdf) does explain the details.

The webstart client does implement pack200 for jardiff files, I tested this with Java 8u31 and a little proof of concept servlet.

I will implement the feature in a servlet and the gradle plugin. Please see the corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin/issues/19) of my plugin for status updates.